# Pig Latin almost done

Tags: javascript, regex

Hello I was able to apply the pig latin to words but when I try to apply it to a sentence it only converts the last word can someone please help me finish the code

```
function translate(string) {
    // body...
    //1.0 split the string i am going to work with and set it to a variable
    let word = string.split("");
    console.log(word);
    //1.1 create the regular expression
    const vowelRegex = /[aeiou]/;
    console.log(vowelRegex);

    //1.2 compare if the first letter of the string matches the vowelRegex
    //meaning that if the string matches any of the vowels of the regex
    if (vowelRegex.test(string[0])) {
        return `${string}way`;
    }
    while (true) {
        if (!vowelRegex.test(word[0])) {
            const firstconsonant = word.splice(0, 1)[0];
            word.push(firstconsonant);
        } else {
            break;
        }
    }
    string = `${word.join("")}ay`;
    return string;
}

console.log(translate("apple"));
console.log(translate("banana"));
console.log(translate("cherry"));
console.log(translate("eat pie"));
console.log(translate("three"));
console.log(translate("school"));
console.log(translate("quiet"));
console.log(translate("square"));
console.log(translate("the quick brown fox"));
```

the problem I am facing is when I have more than one word like "eat pie" it gives back eat pieway and also the sentence "the quick brown fox" it only applies it to fox and it gives back foxthway putting the "th" at the end
I need to apply it to each word individually. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I can tell this is some sort of assignment and currently the context / goal is fuzzy.

Here is a good resource for [Regex](https://regexr.com)

try changing you regex to the following::

```js
function translate(text) {    
  
    const firstVowelRegex = /^[aeiou]/i; // ^ - beginning of string 
    const globalVowelRemove = /[aeiou]/ig; // i,g case insensitive and global  
        
    if (firstVowelRegex.test(text[0])) {   
       text = [text.slice(0, 1), 'way', text.slice(1)].join('').replace(globalVowelRemove, '');
    } else {                
       text = text.replace(globalVowelRemove, '');
    }
    return text + 'ay';
}


console.log(translate("apple"));
console.log(translate("banana"));
console.log(translate("cherry"));
console.log(translate("eat pie"));
console.log(translate("three"));
console.log(translate("school"));
console.log(translate("quiet"));
console.log(translate("square"));
console.log(translate("the quick brown fox"));
```

Regex is super powerful and has been in every programming interview I've ever done.